# Генерация случайных чисел, откуда-то берет минусовые числа, как можно исправить?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Console.Write("Введите от какого числа начинать и нажмите клавишу Enter: ");

    string x = Console.ReadLine();//Получение первой цифр

    int firstArg = Convert.ToInt32(x);//Преобразование первой строки в число

    Console.Write("Введите любое число до какого и нажмите клавишу Enter: ");

    string y = Console.ReadLine();//Получение второй цифры

    int secondArg = Convert.ToInt32(y);//Преобразование второй строки в чис*/

    Console.Write("Введите сколько нужно случайных чисел и нажмите клавишу Enter: ");
    string z = Console.ReadLine();//Получение числа

    int triplArg = Convert.ToInt32(z);//Преобразование число

    int value = rnd.Next(0, 999999);
    for (int i = 1; i < triplArg; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("Результат введенных чисел: "+(rnd.Next(secondArg) - rnd.Next(firstArg)));//Рандомные числа в промежутке

    Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

Comment: Например 1-2=-1. Непонятно зачем вы вычисляете разность

Comment: В следующий раз описывайте задачу в тексте, чтоб не приходилось догадываться по комментариям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно получить случайное число в промежутке от 0 до разницы между двумя введёнными и прибавить к нему нижнюю границу:

```
Console.WriteLine("Результат введенных чисел: "+(rnd.Next(secondArg-firstArg) + firstArg));
```

Вы же вычисляете разность между двумя случайными числами: одно в промежутке от нуля до нижней границы, другое в промежутке от нуля до верхней границы. Очевидно, что иногда второе число больше первого, что приводит к результату ниже нуля.